# Русские символы в консоли

Tags: java, maven, кодировка

При выполнении теста, в консоли не отображаются русские буквы, хотя сам CMD поддерживает русские символы, в системе установлен русский язык.

Имеется класс

```
public class TestTest {
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("english");
    System.out.println("русские");
}
}
```

вывод консоли:

```
 С:\..\ >echo "вваваы"
    "вваваы"

>mvn test 
.....
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestTest
english
╤А╤Г╤Б╤Б╨║╨╕╨╡
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.056 sec
....
```

кодировка консоли ср866. пробовал задать разные кодировки консоли перед запуском - не помогло. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вывести русские символы?

**UPD**

Запуск через Idea отображает корректно.

p.s. оказалось, что Idea автоматически налету приводит все сообщения к человеческому виду

**UPD2**
ни один из ответов не помогло. так что вопрос открыт.

Comment: а Java разве не в юникоде выводит по умолчанию?..

Comment: @pavel, просто они забили на windows. Вот в линуксе бы работало...Наверное :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov я попробовал эти способы - не помогает. чувствую, что проблема в ОС. на ideone.com отрабатывает успешно все всеми кодировками и без.

Comment: @sae не знаю что вы там "пробовали" - но сопсоб рабочий

Comment: @sae что бы не гадать на кофейной гуще - приведите что у вас выводится в консоли в бинарном формате. Перенаправьте вывод в файл - и откройте в hex-редакторе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  не помогло в бинарном формате. 
использование `new Locale("ru")` позволяет в hex-редакторе увидеть, но это не подходит, так как хочется в консоле сразу получить желаемый результат

Comment: @sae где вы по приведенной мной ссылке прочитали про `new Locale("ru")`? С какого вообще перепугу вы решили, что это решит вашу проблему?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не имеет значения где я прочитал. я это написал, как дополнительную инфу, чтобы потом не просили проверить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не помогло в hex-редакторе. все таки хочется сделать так, чтобы результат виден был в консоле или в файле русскими буквами. log4j точно также пишет ( то есть не пишет русские буквы)

Comment: @sae пожалуйста, прочитайте еще раз что я вас просил сделать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov сделал. выводится ромбики и ромбики с точками. нормального текста нет

Comment: @sae Вы не туда смотрите.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46124/discussion-between-sae-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "<кодировка в которой будут отображаться символы к терминале>"));
```

Comment: пробовал несколько вариантов - не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переключить консоль на UTF-8 командой `chcp 65001`.

Comment: пробовал - не помогло

Comment: ну значит `1251`

Comment: Я сразу же несколько пробовал. ни одна не помогает