# Русский текст в maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Использую Selenium+Idea+Maven. как командой **mvn clean test** вывести русский текст, который содержится в

```
driver.getTitle()
```

Comment: может там строка содержится в другой кодировке и ее явно нужно преобразовать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в pom.xml добавить :

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Ну и вообще посмотрите в сторону кодировки utf-8
также проверьте в настройках идеи File>settings>Editor>File encodings , 
посмотрите какая кодировка в run-консоле.

Comment: везде указана UTF-8, добавление в pom не помогло. Если вывести в консоль так System.out.print("какой-то текст"), то все успешно. Если driver.getTitle(), где Title русский, то кракозябры

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571691/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8 вот тут мой вопрос закрыли, хотя ни один из ответов не помогло. я опустил руки

Comment: я пробовал любые кодировки - ни одна не помогла

Comment: Пробовали new String(driver.getTitle().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8") ? Что касается консоли в винде, я еще шрифт какой-то добавлял, точно не помню